# dart - correct coding pattern for subscription when using null saftey?

Tags: dart, null

I've enabled the dart 2.8 experimental null saftey.

I have the following exiting code.

```
StreamSubscription<String> subscription;
    subscription =
        response.transform(Utf8Decoder()).transform(LineSplitter()).listen(
      (line) async {
        result += line;
      },
      onDone: () async {
        unawaited(subscription.cancel());
        completer.complete(result);
      },
    );
```

With null saftey enabled I get a error in the 'onDone' method where it calls subscription.cancl

```
"The expression is nullable and must be null-checked before it can be used.
Try checking that the value isn't null before using it.",
```

I can fix the problem by putting a conditional before the call to cancel, but this seems unnecessary as in reality subscription can never be null.

Is there a coding pattern that allows subscription to be declared as non-null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the read of `subscription` happens at a place where it's still potentially unassigned. It isn't, actually, but we only know that because the `listen` method promises not to call any of the callbacks before returning. The compiler can't see that. So, you need to move the reading to after the assignment.

What I'd do to make this `listen` call work:

```dart
var buffer = StringBuffer(result);
var subscription = response
  .transform(Utf8Decoder())
  .transform(LineSplitter())
  .listen((line) {
    buffer.write(line);
  });
subscription.onDone(() {
    completer.complete(buffer.toString());
  });
```

I removed the `async` from the callbacks because it is not needed. All it does to make these functions async is to return a future that no-one would ever look at.
In general, the callbacks on `Stream` and `Future` should have non-async callbacks.

I also removed the `subscription.cancel` from the `onDone` event handler. If you get a "done" event, the subscription is done, there is no need to cancel it.

I also added a string buffer to avoid the quadratic time and space complexity of repeated string concatenation.

Looking at the code, you seem to be concatenating lines right after splitting them, maybe all you need is:

```dart
  response.transform(Utf8Decoder()).join("").then(completer.complete);
```

I'll assume for now that the splitting+joining is necessary.

In that case, what I'd actually prefer to do instead is of using `listen` is:

```dart
var buffer = StringBuffer();
response
  .transform(Utf8Decoder())
  .transform(LineSplitter())
  .forEach((line) {
    buffer.write(line);
  }).then(() {
    completer.complete(buffer.toString());
  }, onError: (e, s) {
    completer.completeError(e, s);
  });
```

or, if in an async function:

```dart
try {
  var buffer = StringBuffer();
  await for (var line in response.transform(Utf8Decoder()).transform(LineSplitter())) {
    buffer.write(line);
  }
  completer.complete(buffer.toString());  
} catch(e, s) {
  completer.completeError(e, s);
}
```

Comment: 'The problem here is that the read of subscription happens at a place where it's still potentially unassigned'. The maybe I've mis-understood null-safety. My understanding was that if I declare a 'String' rather than 'String?' that I was telling the compiler that I've arranged the code to ensure that the var can't be null But I gather from your statement that I also need to pass the static analysis test?

Comment: The line splitting was necessary (I've simplified the example) but I wasn't aware of the join('') pattern, so good to know.