# Pausing a stream in dart null safety

Tags: dart, subscription

I'm converting dart code to nnbd.

I have the following code.

```dart
   var subscription = response.listen(
        (newBytes) async {
          /// if we don't pause we get overlapping calls from listen
          /// which causes the [writeFrom] to fail as you can't
          /// do overlapping io.
          subscription.pause();

          /// we have new data to save.
          await raf.writeFrom(newBytes);
          subscription.resume();

        });
```

The problem is I get the following error:

```
The non-nullable local variable 'subscription' must be assigned before it can be used.
Try giving it an initializer expression, or ensure that it's assigned on every execution path.
```

I've had a similar problem solved here:
[dart - correct coding pattern for subscription when using null saftey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62925313/dart-correct-coding-pattern-for-subscription-when-using-null-saftey)
which was answered by @lrn

However the pattern solution pattern doesn't seem to work in this case.

raf.writeFrom is an async operation so I must use an 'async' method which means I can't use the 'forEach' solution as again I don't have access to the subscription object.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your code, as written, was legal *before* null-safety either; you can't reference a variable (`subscription`) before it's declared, and the declaration isn't complete until after the expression you initialize it with (`response.listen(...)`) is evaluated.  You will need to separate the declaration from the initialization to break the circular dependency:

```dart
StreamSubscription<List<int>> subscription;
subscription = response.listen(...);
```

Comment: The original code was legal as the listen method guarantees to not generate a callback until after listen returns. The 'late' method however does make sense with nnbd. I will test it out. Thanks!

Comment: @BrettSutton It doesn't matter when the `listen` callback is generated or executed at runtime; it's not *statically* valid code and should fail at compilation time.  I don't know how your code worked before; [DartPad rejects it](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/87bae44ea8d9b520405b5858d524a2a7).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `listen`, I'd do it as:

```dart
var subscription = response.listen(null);
subscription.onData((newBytes) async {
  subscription.pause();
  await raf.writeFrom(newBytes);
  subscription.resume();
});
```

or, without the `async`:

```dart
var subscription = response.listen(null);
subscription.onData((newBytes) {
  subscription.pause(raf.writeFrom(newBytes));
});
```

which will pause the subscription until the future returned by `raf.writeFrom` completes (it shouldn't complete with an error, though).

If using `listen` is not a priority, I'd prefer to use an asynchronous `for`-`in` like:

```dart
await for (var newBytes in subscription) {
  await raf.writeFrom(newBytes);
}
```

which automatically pauses the implicit subscription at the `await` and resumes it when you get back to the loop.

Both with `stream.listen` and the `StreamController` constructor, null safety has made it nicer to create them first without callbacks, and then add the callbacks later, if the callback needs to refer to the subscription/controller.
(That's basically the same nswer as in the linked question, only applied to `onData` instead of `onDone`. You have to pass a default `onData` argument to `listen`, but it can be `null` precisely to support this approach.)