# Why can't I use local variable in a callback?

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's say I've a `stream()` which returns `Stream<int>`. `stream().listen` returns `StreamSubscription`.

```dart
var subs = stream().listen((e) {
  if (someCondition) subs.cancel(); // Error
});
```

I don't understand why is there an error, because by the time I start listening for events in the listen method, I would have definitely a valid object `subs`.

Note: I know this can be done by creating a `StreamSubscription` instance/top-level variable but why they have prevented the use of local variable like this?

Comment: There are no language feature in Dart you can use to indicate that you are not calling a function given as argument right away. Since we in theory could call the function right away this would mean `subs` does not contain any value. Yes, you can make an exception in this specific case, but it will add confusion to the language if you have too many secret features which the language team are only able to make use of.

Comment: @julemand101 Thanks that makes sense!

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/66540160/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely because it's possible that `subs` will be used before it's assigned. We know that the callback passed to listen will be called on stream events, but it's also possible that the callback is called immediately and it's return value or a calculation done by it may be required for the return value of the function it was passed to.

Take this `fakeFunc` for instance, which I made an extension on the `int` class for convenience:

```dart
extension FakeListen on int {
  int fakeFunc(int Function(int x) callback, int val) {
    return callback(val);
  }
}
```

The return value *depends* on the result of `callback`!

```
int subs = x.fakeFunc((e) {
  print(e);
  subs.toString();//error
  return e + 1;
}, 5);
```

I can't use `subs` because `subs` will be guaranteed to not be exist at this point. It's not declared. This can be easily solved by moving the declaration to a separate line, but also forces you to make it nullable. Using `late` here won't even help, because `subs` won't exist by the time you try to use it in the callback.

Your scenario is different, but this is an example of where allowing that would fail. Your scenario involves a callback that is called asynchronously, so there shouldn't be any issues with using `subs` in the callback, but the analyzer doesn't know that. Even async-marked methods could have this issue as async methods run synchronously up until its first `await`. It's up to the programmer to make the right decision, and my guess is that this error is to prevent programmers from making mistakes.

Comment: Want to add that even if "Your scenario involves an asynchronous callback" it still has the behavior that `async` marked methods are running synchronously until the first `await` so we could end up calling the callback method right away even in a `async` marked method.

Answer (score 2):

We know that `Stream.listen` does not call its callback until after a value is returned, but the Dart compiler does not.

Consider the following function, which simply calls a callback and returns the result:

```dart
T execute<T>(T Function() callback) => callback();
```

Now, consider using it to assign a variable:

```dart
int myVariable = execute(() => myVariable + 1);
```

The problem here is that the given callback is called synchronously, before `myVariable` is assigned, but it tries to use `myVariable` to calculate a value!

To resolve this issue with your stream question, you can use the new `late` keyword. Using `late` tells the compiler that you know the variable will be assigned by the time it's accessed.

```dart
late final StreamSubscription<MyType> subscription;
subscription = stream().listen(/* ... */);
```

Comment: Thank you, but even with `late` I can't use local variable in it.

Comment: You need to have the declaration and assignment on separate lines.